# I'm new to Github and having trouble with generating an SSH key

Tags: github, ssh, terminal, permissions

I am following a tutorial from freeCodeCamp.org and at the part where I generate a SSH key (timestamp 20:30), my terminal is saying

zsh: permission denied: /Users/michael .

I am entering the following as instructed

~ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"

I have tried changing security permissions for the terminal in system preferences to allow it to run software that doesn't met the security policy and that doesn't help.
Weirdly, when i tried this the first time, it worked, however when i tried to view the actual key in the terminal it gave my the permissions error message from above so I figured I must have done something wrong, so I deleted the keys it had made in my users directory and started again, only to find that it now won't even generate a key in the first place.

As I say, I am very new to this so I apologise if it is something basic that I am asking but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried the command with sudo? 

sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"

Comment: The `~` is not part of the command. That is likely just (part of) the user's shell prompt.

Comment: Do not use `sudo` without understanding *why* you might need it. The problem here is not that you don't have permission to execute a particular command, but that you are executing the *wrong* command. There is no need to run `ssh-keygen` with root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is just part of the user's prompt in the video. The actual command is just

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"
```

In a shell command, `~` is expanded to the user's home directory, so your shell thinks you wanted to execute a command named `/Users/michael` with arguments `ssh-keygen`, `-t`, etc.

Comment: Ahh thanks everyone for your answers. I have never worked with the terminal like this before so I was going in totally blind. It is good to know that using the ~ is where the problem lies. Thanks again. First time ive posted a question on here and how humbling to see people willing to help just to be kind. Thanks guys!